# Is there a way to detect when a publisher has a new subscriber? | Swift, Combine

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'm developing a MVVM structure with API calls.
I have this structure now:

```
    //Get publisher
    loginPublisher = LoginService.generateLoginPublisher()
        
    //Create a subscriber
    loginSubscriber = loginPublisher!
        .sink { error in
            print("Something bad happened")
            self.isLoading = false
        } receiveValue: { value in               
            
            self.saveClient(value)
            self.client = value
            self.isLoading = false
        }
    
    //Asking service to start assync task and notify its result on publisher
    LoginService.login(email, password, loginPublisher!)
```

Basically what I do is obtain certain publisher from a `LoginService`, then I create a subscriber on `loginPublisher`, and then I tell `LoginService` to make some assync logic and send it result to `loginPublisher` this way I manage sent data with `loginSubscriber`.

I would like to execute LoginService.login() internally when I execute `LoginService.generateLoginPublisher()`, but if I do that, there is a chance that `LoginService.login()` logic finish before I create `loginSubscriber`, that's why I was forced to control when to call `LoginService.login()`.

**How could I detect from LoginService when its publisher has a new subscriber?**

This is my `LoginService` class:

```
class LoginService{
static func generateLoginPublisher() -> PassthroughSubject<Client, NetworkError>{
    return PassthroughSubject<Client, NetworkError>()
}

static func login(_ email: String,_ password: String,_ loginPublisher: PassthroughSubject<Client, NetworkError>){
    let url = NetworkBuilder.getApiUrlWith(extraPath: "login")
    
    print(url)
    
    let parameters: [String: String] = [
        "password": password,
        "login": email
    ]
    
    print(parameters)
    
    let request = AF.request(
        url, method: .post,
        parameters: parameters,
        encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default
    )
    
    request.validate(statusCode: 200...299)
    request.responseDecodable(of: Client.self) { response in
        if let loginResponse = response.value{//Success
            loginPublisher.send(loginResponse)
        }
        else{//Failure
            loginPublisher.send(completion: Subscribers.Completion<NetworkError>.failure(.thingsJustHappen))
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You'll need to write your own publisher for that, and implement in the `subscribe` method the monitoring you want. But note that this might not be the best approach, maybe changing your design will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want full control over subscriptions, you can create a custom `Publisher` and `Subscription`.

`Publisher`'s `func receive<S: Subscriber>(subscriber: S)` method is the one that gets called when the publisher receives a new subscriber.

If you simply want to make a network request when this happens, you just need to create a custom `Publisher` and return a `Future` that wraps the network request from this method.

In general, you should use `Future` for one-off async events, `PassthroughSubject` is not the ideal `Publisher` to use for network requests.

Comment: You are right about PassthroughtSubject not being the best option. I used CurrentValueSubject instead and solved my problem.

Comment: @SebastiánGarcíaBurgos `CurrentValueSubject` is still not the way to do it. As I've said, `Future` is the correct way of handling one off async work, such as network requests

Comment: You're totally right, I have already edited my own answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved my problem using `Future` instead of `PassthroughtSubject` as Dávid Pásztor suggested. Using `Future` I don't have to worried about `LoginService.login()` logic finish before I create `loginSubscriber`.

`LoginSevice.login()` method:

```
static func login(_ email: String,_ password: String) -> Future<Client, NetworkError>{        
    return Future<Client, NetworkError>{ completion in
        let url = NetworkBuilder.getApiUrlWith(extraPath: "login")
        
        print(url)
        
        let parameters: [String: String] = [
            "password": password,
            "login": email
        ]
        
        print(parameters)
        
        let request = AF.request(
            url, method: .post,
            parameters: parameters,
            encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default
        )
        
        request.validate(statusCode: 200...299)
        request.responseDecodable(of: Client.self) { response in
            if let loginResponse = response.value{//Success
                completion(.success(loginResponse))
            }
            else{//Failure
                completion(.failure(NetworkError.thingsJustHappen))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
        loginSubscriber = LoginService.login(email, password)
        .sink { error in
            print("Something bad happened")
            self.isLoading = false
        } receiveValue: { value in
            self.saveClient(value)
            self.client = (value)
            self.isLoading = false
        }
```